# How to extract information from MS project in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ms-project

I have to extract some data from a .MPP file format in Objective-C.

I found nothing  on internet to do so. any idea on how to read the file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, might be indirectly helpful: http://mpxj.sourceforge.net/

> Welcome to `MPXJ`! This library provides a set of facilities to allow
> project information to be manipulated in `Java` and `.Net.` `MPXJ` supports
> seven data formats, `Microsoft Project Exchange (MPX)`, `Microsoft`
> `Project (MPP,MPT)`, `Microsoft Project Data Interchange (MSPDI XML)`,
> `Microsoft Project Database (MPD)`, `Planner (XML)`, and `Primavera (XER`
> `and database)`.
>
> The library is currently based around a set of structures modelled on
> the data described by the MPP file format. All manipulation of project
> data takes place using these data structures, which can be read from
> or written to the various supported file formats. The notes in the
> following paragraphs explain the facilities `MPXJ` offers for each file
> format.

So you might be able to take some of that code and port it to `obj-c` ... good luck!

Comment: I already download this Library ... but is there any other way or any other Objective-C lib ?

Comment: not that I know of. if you do manage to port it to obj-c, it would make a great contribution back to that project ... contributions keep the open source world turning :-)

Comment: Your answer was helpful to me , I will try to port this library to Objective-C

Comment: Rather than porting the library directly, you may want to take a look at XMLVM [link](http://xmlvm.org). This project will allow you to generate standard C from the JAR files, which you can consume in your Objective C. A similar approach allows me to ship a .Net version of MPXJ without having to manually port the code. (In this case I use IKVM to produce the .Net assemblies). At some point I will probably include the necessary ant build script with MPXJ to support XMLVM. If you feel like contributing one...